# Why does Immutable.js throw Invalid key path on Map.setIn()

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I must be missing something here because the [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) make it out as if the below code should work just fine but I get an invalid keypath error... Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/hally9k/pen/gMPYEJ?editors=1011).

```
var map1 = Immutable.Map({ 'selector': { 'type': 'bar' }});
var map2 = map1.setIn(['selector', 'type'], 'foo');
console.log(map2.toJS());
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This happens because the key `'selector'` has a non-Map value.
`setIn` will work if we make sure that the value for `'selector'` is also an Immutable Map:

```js
var map1 = Immutable.Map({ 'selector': Immutable.Map({ 'type': 'bar' })});
var map2 = map1.setIn(['selector', 'type'], 'foo');
console.log(map1.toJS());  
console.log(map2.toJS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

To deeply convert JavaScript Objects and Arrays to Maps and Lists you can use [`fromJS()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS). So you can more easily write:

```js
var map3 = Immutable.fromJS({ 'selector': { 'type': 'bar' }});
var map4 = map3.setIn(['selector', 'type'], 'foo');
console.log(map3.toJS());  
console.log(map4.toJS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

Comment: So if I have a deeply nested object that I want to make changes to I have to recursively map every level of nesting manually? This seems a bit, well, cumbersome tbh.

Comment: That was for illustration. You can use [`fromJS()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) to deeply convert JavaScript Objects and Arrays to Maps and Lists.